# Prevent background image from streching in Android layout

Tags: android, android-layout, responsive-design

I have an image which I want to use as background in layout and then I want to add another views like textview over this background. Now problem is I don't want this background to stretch in different devices or screen sizes. I want it to keep it in same size and then wrap my other views inside this background image.

[image: this is the image with Relative layout and imageview as a background]

Things I have tried to achieve this:

1. I searched on StackOverflow but I didn't find any relevant solution to my problem.
2. I tried to use this background image in Linear, Relative and Framelayout but then it streches the image just like this:

[image: framelayout streches the background image same goes for linear and relative layout]

Only ImageView can prevent it from streching but as you know we cannot use Imageview as a container.

Comment: you can put ImageView below your container

Comment: A hack would be to use a portrait image and use centercrop property of the imageview.

Comment: @VladMatvienko then I won't be able to use the width and height properties of the image in other views. Somehow I just want to use this image as container. So, I cannot put my imageview outside the container.

Comment: actually you can use it's dimensions as width and height. So you want to know how?

Comment: @Madhav Can you please elaborate ? If I set centercrop property of the imageview then again question arises how am I suppose to use it as container for other view?

Comment: @VladMatvienko yes please

Comment: you can place your imageView setting it's width and height to wrap_content at the bottom of a FrameLayout, and on the top of it you can placeany container having winth and height set to match_parent. This way ImageView will take as much space as it wants, and the container will take as much space, as ImageView took

Comment: @VladMatvienko still not working or may be I'm doing it wrong. Linearlayout container is still not matching width and height of its parent.

http://imgur.com/a/v6ZNW

Comment: try adding some view to that LinearLayout. Also you added ImageView on top of the layout, not to the bottom

Comment: @VladMatvienko Thanks for your help but this is not what I want. according to your method, linear layout's widht and height is acting like wrap_content even after I'm using match_parent for it. see this example.. I have put a EditText inside it. Its not working like a true container.
http://imgur.com/a/2O4iR